# Invoke wont invoke?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, textbox, invoke

I'm doing this:

```
    Delegate Sub SetTextBoxText_Delegate(ByVal [Label] As TextBox, ByVal [text] As String)
' The delegates subroutine.  

Public Sub SetTextBoxText_ThreadSafe(ByVal [Label] As TextBox, ByVal [text] As String)
    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.  
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.  
    If [Label].InvokeRequired Then
        MsgBox("invoke")
        Dim MyDelegate As New SetTextBoxText_Delegate(AddressOf SetTextBoxText_ThreadSafe)
        Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[Label], [text]})
    Else
        MsgBox("noinvoke")
        [Label].Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

However it always uses noinvoke. If I try setting it normaly it gives me a thread-safe warning and doesn't work. If I force invoke then it says the control isn't created?

Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because the control has not yet been created when you try to access it. Wait until the control has loaded, or check it using `Label.Created`. Like so:

```
Public Sub SetTextBoxText_ThreadSafe(ByVal Label As TextBox, ByVal text As String)
    If Label.Created Then
        If Label.InvokeRequired Then
            MsgBox("invoke")
            Dim MyDelegate As New SetTextBoxText_Delegate(AddressOf SetTextBoxText_ThreadSafe)
            Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {Label, text})
        Else
            MsgBox("noinvoke")
            Label.Text = text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

P.S. You don't need a custom delegate type, just use `Action(Of TextBox, String)`. You also don't need square brackets around `Label` or `text`.

Comment: I'm using the windows form editor and I know the textbox is there :l The textbox exists.

Comment: @meow: Yes, it might exist, but it might not have been created yet. When do you start the secondary thread?

Comment: @meow: Okay, there's the problem. The form hasn't truly been created yet. I've added an example to my post.

Comment: Ah. How do I do this then? This is my first time working with multiple threads :(

Comment: Um, no, I don't know how to "truly create" a form

Comment: @meow: Just fix your `SetTextBoxText_ThreadSafe` method to reflect what I wrote in my answer (see the edit) and it should work. Unless you're only updating the TextBox once? In that case, a quick fix would be to put your code in Form.Shown instead of Form.Load.

Comment: It always says the TextBox is not loaded, so it doesn't set it.